# Top software to install on Live USB drive, for Windows recovery purposes

Tags: windows, live-usb, lubuntu

I installed the latest **Lubuntu** image on a pen drive(2GB), using **Ubuntu's Startup Disk Creator**.
My goal for this pen drive is for maintenance of old Windows XP machines.

What software should I install for this?  Whether it is already in the Ubuntu repository or not.

### Note:

- This is a **Community Wiki** page.
- I already know some of what to install and that that there are preconfigured distributions for this purpose.  I just want a public list for reference (In case I missed something).
- **Please mention ONE software per question posted,** for better voting.

Answer (score 7):

testdisk/photorec. Great tools for recovering deleted files and repairing disk partitions.

Answer (score 7):

gparted, if it's not the part of default install.

Answer (score 5):

[dd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_%28Unix%29), for low level transfer between drives. It should already be there, so you won't need to install it, but it's good to be aware of.

Here's an example from Wikipedia to copy a partition from one drive to another:

```
dd if=/dev/sda2 of=/dev/sdb2 bs=4096 conv=noerror
```

There's a *lot* more you can do with this, like rewriting arbitrary blocks, creating drive images, converting files, etc.

Answer (score 5):

The second one is [foremost](http://foremost.sourceforge.net/) a great tool to recover lost files.

Answer (score 4):

**Disk Usage Analyzer**.  Handy for verifying where big files are located.  It's found in the repository, if it's not part of the default install.

Answer (score 3):

You might also want to look in to creating a windows live cd, or windows-pe as it is also come times called.
http://www.nu2.nu/pebuilder/

Answer (score 2):

I do it too.

The first thing that I install to it is [Avast!](http://www.avast.com/es-ww/linux-home-edition). It's a great way of checking windows machines for viruses.

Answer (score 2):

[Ophcrack](http://ophcrack.sourceforge.net/%22ophcrack%22), for Windows password recovery (aka password cracking).

Comment: It's already found in the repository.

Answer (score 2):

**clamav**, for antivirus protection.  It can be found in Ubuntu's repository.

Answer (score 1):

**AVG**, for antivirus protection.
You can download the .deb file from their web site.