# Which software should I use on Ubuntu to create a Windows XP LiveUSB?

Tags: 12.04, installation, windows, lubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create Windows XP LiveUSB using Ubuntu to replace it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151073/how-to-create-windows-xp-liveusb-using-ubuntu-to-replace-it)

Since many programs that I need only work on XP, I need to install Windows XP on my 2 laptops but I can't use an optical drive, which makes using a USB the only option.

If it helps, I can tell you that I used to have Vista and Windows 7 on my 2 laptops but I clean installed Ubuntu 12.04 on one, and Lubuntu on the other. Also I have no trace of Windows left on any of my laptops, when I bought my laptops they came without a Windows CD, so I only had a 20GB partition on my hard drives (which I formatted when I clean installed Ubuntu and Lubuntu.)

Also, I have no problem with clean installing Windows XP and the reinstalling Ubuntu/Lubuntu so I can dual boot.

Thanks!

Edit: I have a ISO file ready, on a USB.

Comment: The tittle of your question should be "Which software should I use on Ubuntu to create a Windows XP LiveUSB"

Comment: Web-E: I've already searched around the web and read quite a few links on how to do it. I've even read the link you've posted. Maybe I'm just looking incorrectly, but I can't find how it would help me?

Also, I've used UNetBootin, but I had the same problem as the OP of the link you provided. All I get is a blue screen with default, and when the countdown finishes it restarts the countdown and does nothing.

Comment: I don't know whether it will work, but I think you should try using dd

Comment: Another duplicate that describes a solution for Windows XP: http://askubuntu.com/questions/47362/how-to-create-a-live-usb-for-windows-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

1. Install GPARTED (`sudo apt-get install gparted`) and format your USB Drive as NTFS.
2. Install unetbootin from the Ubuntu Software Centre.
3. Point to your XP iso and select your USB drive and press OK.
4. Boot from it
5. Done!

Comment: unetbootin don't give you ntfs as an option

Answer (score 0):

You can use unetbootin. that you can install with

```
sudo apt-get install unetbootin
```

Comment: If i use unetbootin I get the same problem as:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/3241/top-software-to-install-on-live-usb-drive-for-windows-recovery-purposes?rq=1

All I get is a blue screen with default, and when the countdown finishes it restarts the countdown and does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

[WinUSB](http://en.congelli.eu/prog_info_winusb.html) worked fine for me last time I set up a dual-boot. You can install it either from the `.deb` package provided on the homepage or through a PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:colingille/freshlight
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install winusb
```

The GUI should be straightforward and easy to use:

[image]

Comment: It seems that WinUSB doesn't work for XP:

"Supported images: Windows Vista, Seven, 8 installer for any language and any version (home, pro...) and Windows PE."

Comment: That's too bad. It might work anyway. I would try it out, if I were you.

Answer (score 0):

To have a live USB with XP i suggest this way:

1. With an iso xp create a bootable CD for windows xp
2. From setup set cd first boot for your laptop
3. Insert the bootable CD for windows xp and the usb to your laptop
4. Booting from cd windows xp. when you asked where to install xp
5. CHOOSE the USB

After finish the installation you have a USB with windows XP installed. Insert it to your laptop and set first boot from USB. Windows XP will run.